# Can't connect to localhost mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to make a simple form that can be stored on mysql database. Whenever I try to connect it won't let me. Here's what I have:

PHP:

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'forms1');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysqli_error());
}

$value = $_POST['input1'];
$value2 = $_POST['input2'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO demo (input1, input2) VALUES ('$value', '$value2')";

if (!mysqli_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
}

mysqli_close();
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="demo.php" method="post" />
<p>Input 1: <input type="text" name="input1" /></p>
<p>Input 2: <input type="text" name="input2" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I the correct credentials, but when I open up my page it says this, "Can't use forms1:"

Doesn't even give me the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will give you an error message if you add the connection variable to the call to `mysqli_error()`

```
if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysqli_error($link));
}
```

This applied to all calls to `mysqli_error($link)`

> The [PHP MYSQLI Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

This mistake should have generated a PHP error, so if you did not see that I assume you are developing on a LIVE server where error reporting is turned off. In that case you should start all your scripts like this

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

This will ensure that you see these errors on the browser! Once a script is debugged you should probably remove these lines as you dont want a user to see this information should something go wrong while it is a LIVE site

Also the connect should contain the database name,

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'forms1');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

//$db_selected = mysqli_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);
//if (!$db_selected) {
//    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysqli_error());
//}
```

The `mysqli_select_db()` call is there so you can change to another database on the same connection if you were using 2 databases for some reason.

> I assume you are converting from the `mysql_` API to `mysqli_` API unfortunately the convertion is not a one to one conversion.

Comment: Thanks, I've applied all the fixes and it now only shows 1 error:
"Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in D:\MAMP\htdocs\basic\demo.php on line 16". This is line 16: "$db_selected = mysqli_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);". It doesn't think $link is mysqli?

Comment: You dont need the `mysqli_select_db()` as the Database is now mentioned in the `mysqli_connect()` That is why I commented it out

Comment: Ah, got it. I got it to go through with or without it anyways, but it gives me a new error regardless: "Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\MAMP\htdocs\basic\demo.php on line 27". Line 27 is "if (!mysqli_query($sql)) {".

Comment: Ken Please Read the manual. `mysqli_*` functions are not the old `mysql_*` functions.